# How to save edittext to file in Kotlin when using a fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to save an edittext input to a file upon clicking a button, but the app keeps crashing when I use the writeText command. Note, I am trying to do this in a fragment. Any ideas on what is causing the app to crash?

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? =
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info, container, false)

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    SaveInfo_button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        val vehicleNumber: String = vehicleNumberField.text.toString()
        File("data.txt").writeText(vehicleNumber)
        vehicleNumberField.setText("")
        Toast.makeText(activity?.applicationContext, vehicleNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    })
}
```

Comment: Post the relevant lines from the logcat. There you will see which exception you did not catch.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: data.txt: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Comment: You should use a full file path. Not only a file name.

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    SaveInfo_button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        val vehicleNumber = vehicleNumberField.text.toString()
        saveText(vehicleNumber.toByteArray(), applicationContext)
        Toast.makeText(activity?.applicationContext, vehicleNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    })
}
```

pack this method into a separate object, for example like this:

```
object Logs {
    fun saveText(text: ByteArray, context: Context) {
        val file =
            File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "data.text")
        try {
            FileOutputStream(file).apply {
                write(text)
                flush()
                close()
            }
        } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
            Log.d(null, "error writing log file")
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Why dont you use .writeText() as OP does?

Comment: @blackapps Thank you for your question. Actually I have never tried this. How do you do this? Do you use `.writeText()` for this? Feel free to post your solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I only asked that because OP used it. You can see that in the posted code. I never used that myself either so i like to know from you if it works.

Comment: @BWappsandmore thanks a lot for the answer! I get an error when I use "applicationContext" as the context for the saveText function. It is unresolved. How does this work? Do I need to update this anywhere else?

Comment: try with `saveText(vehicleNumber.toByteArray(), getApplicationContext())` instead. Please accept my answer, if it worked for you.

Comment: @BWappsandmore I tried with "getApplicationContext()" before but it still says it is unresolved.

Comment: Maybe you could call this method directly from your activity and use the `Context` from the activity. Pass the content from your `EditText` into a field from the activity and then call the method from there. In that case you won't have the unresolved issue anymore.